# Multiple Glossaries

Tags: glossaries

I want to create different glossaries using the glossaries package.

For example I want one for Astrophysics terms, one for Thermodynamics etc.

I read the package documentation but could not fully understand it without a clear example.

Could anyone demonstrate how to achieve this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the code below will help you. Besides you do not need to label the entries (like `astro:c`), but personally i find the code within the document clearer.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\loadglsentries{example-glossaries-brief}

\newglossary*{astro}{Astrophysics}
\newglossary*{thermo}{Thermodynamics}

\newglossaryentry{astro:c}
{
    type=astro,
    name={\ensuremath{c} },
    description={Ligthspeed},
}
\newglossaryentry{thermo:T}
{
    type=thermo,
    name={\ensuremath{T} },
    description={Temperature},
}

\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
\glsaddall[types={astro,thermo}]

\printglossary[type=astro]
\printglossary[type=thermo]
\end{document}
```