# Multiple glossaries in a memoir class

Tags: memoir, glossaries

I am looking for a way of making multiple glossaries (somewhere between 5-7) in a memoir class document.

In my research, I have found questions with answers in this forum such as [More than one source of glossaries in one file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383813/more-than-one-source-of-glossaries-in-one-file) and [Multiple glossaries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/539508/multiple-glossaries), but I can't make the answers work even as they are. Are those options obsolete and not working? Are there other options nowadays?

So, just as an example, from the first link, I made file1.txt, file2.txt and main.text with the following code, copied from the answer. The output is just a blank page with the page number. Same happens with the code in the answer from the second link too.

**File1.txt**

\newglossaryentry{electrics}
{
name={electrics},
description={ rozvod elektriny, elektrina }
}

```
\newglossaryentry{light}
{
    name={light},
    description={ svetlo $\bullet$ lampa $\bullet$ zapaľovač  },
    plural={lights}
}
```

**File2.txt**

```
\newglossaryentry{electrics_2}
 {
     name={electrics},
     description={ rozvod elektriny, elektrina }
 }

 \newglossaryentry{light_2}
 {
     name={light},
     description={ svetlo $\bullet$ lampa $\bullet$64uj  },
        plural={lights}
 }
```

**Main.tex**

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=english, slovak]{babel}
\usepackage[nomain]{glossaries}% Turn off main glossary (if you don't have one)

% Create two new glossaries (so you can customize them to your liking)
\newglossary[nlg]{gloss1}{not}{ntn}{Glossary 1} 
\newglossary[slg]{gloss2}{sot}{stn}{Glossary 2}

\makeglossaries
\loadglsentries[gloss1]{file1.txt} % Load file1 contents into Glossary 1
\loadglsentries[gloss2]{file2.txt} % Load file2 contents into Glossary 2

\begin{document}
\glsaddall % Just to add all glossary entries, for exemplary purposes
some text

\printglossary[type=gloss1] % I want to print words from file file1.txt here.

\clearpage
some text

\printglossary[type=gloss2] % I want to print words from file file2.txt here.

\end{document}
```